# How to send an email to an arbitrary address and merge in Lead values?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I need to send an email:

- to an arbitrary email address
- using an email template
- merging in values from a Lead

The code would look something like this:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
msg.setToAddresses(new String[] { 'me@somedomain.com' });
msg.setSaveAsActivity(false);

// this causes a runtime error. Lead ID not allowed 
msg.setWhatId(lead.Id);

msg.setTemplateId(templateID);
messages.add(msg);
```

Problem is, you cannot use a Lead ID for the WhatID. I'm not sending an email to the Lead, so I can't use the Lead for the TargetObjectId.

Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't tried it but can't your email template e a vforce page with regular HTML or plaintext output (content-type controlled)? In theory at least that would allow you a controller+extension approach to lead (via target) from which you can load other stuff you need for binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frustrating that SFDC still doesn't support a more flexible templating context, isn't it? Given your constraints, I think you do have options:

- do your own templating replacement by loading the template dynamically and replacing home-grown tags with lead fields (e.g. $LEAD.NAME or whatever)
- temporarily save the Lead as a supported object (Account perhaps?), persist it, use that as the WhatId, send your email, and then rollback/delete (EDIT: as pointed out above, rollback apparently "unsends" emails, so don't use that.)
- use a third-party or custom off-platform mail solution that offers template-based merging that is more flexible than Apex, probably via a WS API

I've played with all of these approaches but the only one I've seriously implemented is #3. Option 1 seems like an attractive option assuming you can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, at least not with salesforce email templates. Even if you were able to set a lead as the whatId you can't use a template with setToAddresses, setTargetObjectId is mandatory when using templates:

> The ID of the contact, lead, or user to which the email will be sent.

From http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=WhatId|whatId|whatIds

To work around this I've had to create a contact, populate it's email, save it, send the email, and then delete the contact (Database.rollback will "unsend" emails, so it won't work here).

I'd try putting all the info from the lead record you need into the contact you create to send the email, but that's a horrible hack. Then again creating and deleting a contact to send an email is already such a hack I can't immagine this makes it much worse.